# Relationship between closure under pushouts and closure under cobase-change?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category with pushouts. Let $\mathcal L \subseteq Mor(\mathcal C)$ be a class of morphisms in $\mathcal C$. Consider the following conditions on $\mathcal L$:

0. Every identity morphism is in $\mathcal L$;
1. $\mathcal L$ is closed under pushouts in the arrow category $\mathcal C^{[1]}$;
2. $\mathcal L$ is closed under cobase-change: if $(A \to B) \in \mathcal L$, then for any $A \to C$, the resulting map $(C \to B \cup_A C) \in \mathcal L$.
3. $\mathcal L$ satisfies cancellation: if $gf \in \mathcal L$ and $f \in \mathcal L$, then $g \in \mathcal L$.

I was surprised to learn from Mathieu Anel that $(0) + (1)$ implies both $(2)$ and $(3)$ -- in both cases, the result follows by considering a single well-chosen map of pushout squares. (In particular, this means that Definition 5.5.5.1(3) of HTT is redundant.)

**Question:** Does the converse hold? That is, does $(0) + (2)+(3) \Rightarrow (1)$?

I suspect the answer is *no*, and it would be nice to have a counterexample. But I believe something related is true. Consider the following condition:

4. $\mathcal L$ is closed under composition

**Claim:** $(2) + (3) + (4) \Rightarrow (1)$

**Proof:** Consider a map of pushout squares from $P = B \cup_A C$ to $P' = B' \cup_{A'} C'$ where the maps $A \to A', B \to B', C \to C'$ are in $\mathcal L$. The resulting cube is cocartesian, so the map $P \to P'$ is the composite $P \to B' \cup_B P \to B' \cup_{A' \cup_A C} C' = P'$. The two maps being composed can be seen to lie in $\mathcal L$ using $(2)$ and $(3)$. Thus the composite map $P \to P'$ lies in $\mathcal L$ by $(4)$.